# Looking for a good approach to set up an F5/Netscaler lab on MacOS (docker + virtualuzation)

Tags: docker, virtualization, mac

To explain myself - I mainly work with Load Balancers - up to now I used VMWare to set up a local lab with couple of F5s and Netscalers, some web server in the backend, and from time to time a Windows Server to fiddle with some AD stuff.
Now - for reasons I really find myself hard to explain I switched to Macbook Pro with M1 processor. And on M1 processor I can't virtualize x86 systems (so bye bye F5 and Netscaler image).

My initial thoughts went to docker - as far as I know this might work in my case, however I'm totally green with this container stuff, so I though you guys could give me  a push in a proper direction.

As far as i learned in the past days, Macbooks do limit access to container networks, and one has to use port redirection to access the applications. This would be a big issue with Load Balancers, as their usage do rely on proper IP addressing.

Is there a good way to work around this - so I could just use and IPs from a private network to reach management and VIPs on my devices (and obviously let them communicate with backend)? With VMWare it was as easy as configuring the vmnet.cfg. I just want to reach everything easily from my host.

Or - since there is way more help on the Internet with Linux hosting Docker - Can I install a VM with a Linux of my choice on Mac, and use Docker within that Linux? Or is that too much hassle for the job?

Would really appreciate some pointers to help me get started with this whole setup.